# iOS UICollectionvView cell different layout for landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want make screen in which collection view Cell should fill whole width of screen while device is in portrait ,
and when device rotates collection view shows 2 cells in 1 section.

For better visualisation see below image.

[image]

[image]

I tried to make cell width = device width (for portrait) but in landscape cell shows in centre of screen.

Will it possible to make such design using collection view ?
If it is possible then how do I achieve this? OR any other idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I think your question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556554/change-uicollectionviewcell-size-on-different-device-orientations

Answer (score 1):

Use size class to position landscape or portrait in different ways.

Have a look to this detailled article [go to Add constraints for generic size class](http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/)

Comment: This is the best way to accomplish this, as it allows for better control of the cell's layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#define kNumberOfCellsInARowPortrait 1
#define kNumberOfCellsInARowLandscape 2

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 0;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation)) {
        CGFloat cellWidth = floor((CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds)-5) / kNumberOfCellsInARowLandscape);
        return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);
    } else {
        CGFloat cellWidth = floor((CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds)-5) / kNumberOfCellsInARowPortrait);
        return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);
    }
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```