# Understanding resize of a UIView with subview(UICollectionView) in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

[image]

**"My View"** has a subview (**UICollectionView**). The subview size is portrait mode 0,0,375,50.

When I launch the app. in landscape following are the results.

Window size in landscape mode is 0,0,375,667.

"My View" resize's in landscape mode, subview also resize's. But the subview size is still 0,0,375,50.

I was expecting subview.bounds to return 0,0,667,50.

The following answer says use bounds , but for me its not working. View resize's but bounds are incorrect.

[Reporting incorrect bounds in landscape Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194504/reporting-incorrect-bounds-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the constraint and Thank to [this answer by Followben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556554/change-uicollectionviewcell-size-on-different-device-orientations) you can recalculate base on your view orientation and divide it by your array count

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    // Adjust cell size for orientation
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
        return CGSizeMake(170.f, 170.f); //Make sure you calculate This
    }
    return CGSizeMake(192.f, 192.f); //Make sure you calculate This
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Great one, difficult to catch and easy to solve. Layout update was required when orientation changes

Comment: Yes, glad we solve this together. Always ping me in the chat room if you have any question, I will help when and if I can. Cheers!